Problem with shared librairies with AnyDesk
I install Anydesk on a Rasberry Pi 5 and when I laucnh it i've got this error :
error while loading shared libraries libatk-1.0.so.0: ELF load command address/offset not page_aligned
Thanks for helping me !

what is your question?  ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post
